# Leaflet Map in Shiny renders a couple of times and then stops

Tags: shiny, leaflet

My code renders fine in rStudio, but when I run it in Shiny, it stops after a few times of running perfectly well. I do have 157,000 rows and 62 columns, but even when I reduce the data set to around 30,000 rows it still behaves the same way. Any idea why this may be? The maps usually run a few times more if I am selecting country-level, region-level or year-level data, but cr@ps out quicker if I select All years and countries -- usually after running just once.

```
output$map_leaflet = renderLeaflet({
reduced.data = reduced() #reactive expression that gets filtered data

m = leaflet(reduced.data) %>% addProviderTiles("NASAGIBS.ViirsEarthAtNight2012") %>%

  addCircleMarkers(~longitude, ~latitude, popup = ~summary, radius= 7, color = "red")})
```